# How do you get a node's children?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a parent node with two children ( and multiple grandchildren ).  How do I select just the children of given node ( but not the node itself )?

The other functions edgesWith and edgesTo link two collections together, I just want the children of a node.

I've tried this unsuccessfully

```
$('#cy').cytoscape({
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'content': 'data(name)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'color': 'white',
        'text-outline-width': 2,
        'text-outline-color': '#888'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      })
    .selector(':selected')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      })
    .selector('.faded')
      .css({
        'opacity': 0.25,
        'text-opacity': 0
      }),

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry' } },
      { data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine' } },
      { data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer' } },
      { data: { id: 'g', name: 'George' } }
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e' } },
      { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k' } },
      { data: { source: 'j', target: 'g' } }
    ]
  },

  ready: function(){
    window.cy = this;

    // Elaine, Kramer, George should be blue!
    cy.elements('node[id="j"] node').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your ready function to the following:

```
ready: function() {
  window.cy = this;

  var edgesFromJerry = cy.elements('edge[source="j"]');
  var jerryChildren = edgesFromJerry.target();
  jerryChildren.css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  So how is "node node" and "node > node" used exactly?

Comment: Those selectors are used for compound nodes--which I *believe* are where you have a graph as a node in an outer graph. Not as a sub-graph---think more along the lines of different levels of detail. Another analogy might be a web page where you can have a *div* inside another *div*.

Answer (score 0):

Slight changes from Matthew Burke's answer which selects all children instead of one child.

```
   ready: function() {
      window.cy = this;

      var edgesFromJerry = cy.edges('edge[source="j"]');
      var jerryChildren = edgesFromJerry.targets();
      jerryChildren.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
```

Posting as answer instead of comment as answers in comments tend to be a hard find